# Open GL problem with vertex shader on android emulator, typename expected

Tags: filter, opengl-es, android-emulator, vertex-shader

I have very little understanding about shaders and this one is not mine. It just can't be loaded on my emulator and it gives me an error in the form of a log file. To elaborate more on the problem: i'm using the Drastic emulator for DS games, this is only a filter o shader for such emulator but i doesn't seem to load.
The log file says:
0:18: L0001: Typename expected, found '\'
So i'm asking to see where the problem is...

I tried very little, since i know very little:
First i tried changing a bit the code, before the log said it found "if" so i moved it down to see if it would do something and it resulted in founding "\" and now i don't know anymore since i'm stupid...
The code is in a file with the extension .dsd and is the following:

```
<vertex>

attribute vec2 a_vertex_coordinate;
attribute vec2 a_texture_coordinate;
    
uniform vec4 u_texture_size;
varying vec4 v_texture_coordinate;
varying vec4 v_texture_coordinate_1;

void main()
{
    vec2 ps = vec2(1.0 / u_texture_size.z, 1.0 / u_texture_size.w);
    float dx = ps.x;
    float dy = ps.y;
    gl_Position = vec4(a_vertex_coordinate.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
    v_texture_coordinate = a_texture_coordinate.xyxy;
    v_texture_coordinate_1.xy = vec2(0.0,-dy); // B
    v_texture_coordinate_1.zw = vec2(-dx,0.0); // D
}
</vertex>
<fragment>
    const vec3 dtt = vec3(65536.0, 255.0, 1.0);

    float reduce(vec3 color) {
        return dot(color, dtt);
    }
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec4 u_texture_size;
varying vec4 v_texture_coordinate;
varying vec4 v_texture_coordinate_1;

#define FILTRO(PE, PI, PH, PF, PG, PC, PD, PB, PA, G5, C4, G0, C1, I4, I5, N15, N14, N11, F, H)
\
    if ( PE!=PH && ((PH==PF && ( (PE!=PI && (PE!=PB || PE!=PD || PB==C1 && PD==G0 || PF!=PB && PF!=PC || PH!=PD && PH!=PG)) \
       || (PE==PG && (PI==PH || PE==PD || PH!=PD)) \
       || (PE==PC && (PI==PH || PE==PB || PF!=PB)) ))\
       || (PE!=PF && (PE==PC && (PF!=PI && (PH==PI && PF!=PB || PE!=PI && PF==C4) || PE!=PI && PE==PG)))) ) \
                 {\
                    N11 = (N11+F)*0.5;\
                    N14 = (N14+H)*0.5;\
                    N15 = F;\
                 }\
    else if (PE!=PH && PE!=PF && (PH!=PI && PE==PG && (PF==PI && PH!=PD || PE!=PI && PH==G5)))\
    {\
                N11 = (N11+H)*0.5;\
                N14 = N11;\
                N15 = H;\
    }\
    
void main()
{
    vec2 fp = fract(v_texture_coordinate.xy * u_texture_size.zw);
    
    vec2 g1 = v_texture_coordinate_1.xy * (step(0.5,fp.x) + step(0.5, fp.y) - 1.0) + v_texture_coordinate_1.zw * (step(0.5,fp.x) - step(0.5, fp.y));
    vec2 g2 = v_texture_coordinate_1.xy * (step(0.5,fp.y) - step(0.5, fp.x)) + v_texture_coordinate_1.zw * (step(0.5,fp.x) + step(0.5, fp.y) - 1.0);
        
    vec3 A = texture2D(u_texture, v_texture_coordinate.xy + g1 + g2 ).xyz;
    vec3 B = texture2D(u_texture, v_texture_coordinate.xy + g1      ).xyz;
    vec3 C = texture2D(u_texture, v_texture_coordinate.xy + g1 - g2 ).xyz;
    vec3 D = texture2D(u_texture, v_texture_coordinate.xy      + g2 ).xyz;
    vec3 E = texture2D(u_texture, v_texture_coordinate.xy           ).xyz;
    vec3 F = texture2D(u_texture, v_texture_coordinate.xy      - g2 ).xyz;
    vec3 G = texture2D(u_texture, v_texture_coordinate.xy - g1 + g2 ).xyz;
    vec3 H = texture2D(u_texture, v_texture_coordinate.xy - g1      ).xyz;
    vec3 I = texture2D(u_texture, v_texture_coordinate.xy - g1 - g2 ).xyz;
    
    vec3 A1 = texture2D(u_texture, v_texture_coordinate.xy + 2.0 * g1 + g2 ).xyz;
    vec3 C1 = texture2D(u_texture, v_texture_coordinate.xy + 2.0 * g1 - g2 ).xyz;
    vec3 A0 = texture2D(u_texture, v_texture_coordinate.xy + g1 + 2.0 * g2 ).xyz;
    vec3 G0 = texture2D(u_texture, v_texture_coordinate.xy - g1 + 2.0 * g2 ).xyz;
    vec3 C4 = texture2D(u_texture, v_texture_coordinate.xy + g1 - 2.0 * g2 ).xyz;
    vec3 I4 = texture2D(u_texture, v_texture_coordinate.xy - g1 - 2.0 * g2 ).xyz;
    vec3 G5 = texture2D(u_texture, v_texture_coordinate.xy - 2.0 * g1 + g2 ).xyz;
    vec3 I5 = texture2D(u_texture, v_texture_coordinate.xy - 2.0 * g1 - g2 ).xyz;
        
    vec3 E11 = E;
    vec3 E14 = E;
    vec3 E15 = E;
        
    float a = reduce(A);    
    float b = reduce(B);
    float c = reduce(C);
    float d = reduce(D);
    float e = reduce(E);
    float f = reduce(F);
    float g = reduce(G);
    float h = reduce(H);
    float i = reduce(I);
        
    float  a1 = reduce( A1);
    float  c1 = reduce( C1);
    float  a0 = reduce( A0);
    float  g0 = reduce( G0);
    float  c4 = reduce( C4);
    float  i4 = reduce( I4);
    float  g5 = reduce( G5);
    float  i5 = reduce( I5);
        
    FILTRO(e, i, h, f, g, c, d, b, a, g5, c4, g0, c1, i4, i5, E15, E14, E11, F, H);
    gl_FragColor.rgb = (fp.x < 0.50) ? ((fp.x < 0.25) ? ((fp.y < 0.25) ? E15: (fp.y < 0.50) ? E11: (fp.y < 0.75) ? E14: E15) : ((fp.y < 0.25) ? E14: (fp.y < 0.50) ? E  : (fp.y < 0.75) ? E  : E11)) : ((fp.x < 0.75) ? ((fp.y < 0.25) ? E11: (fp.y < 0.50) ? E  : (fp.y < 0.75) ? E   : E14) : ((fp.y < 0.25) ? E15: (fp.y < 0.50) ? E14: (fp.y < 0.75) ? E11 : E15));
}
</fragment>
```

This code is used from the .dfx file if i'm not mistaken, so here's also the dfx:

```
<options>
name=4XBR v1.1 Low configuration
textures=1
</options>

<fheader>
#if GL_ES
#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
precision highp float;
#else
precision mediump float;
#endif
#endif
</fheader>

<texture:0>
input=framebuffer
min_filter=GL_NEAREST
mag_filter=GL_NEAREST
</texture>

<pass>
shader=4XBR_v1.1_Low configuration.dsd
sampler:u_texture=0
</pass>
```

This should be everything i have gone through, if anyone can help me it would be immensely appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the naming used this shader is using the OpenGL ES 2.0 shader language (`#version 100`). Line continuation isn't supported in ESSL 1.0, so this shader is relying on a vendor extension or out-of-spec behavior.

Line continuation support was added in OpenGL ES 3.0 shader language (#version 300 es), but if you enable that you need to fix the rest of the shader input and output declarations to use the new style (`in` rather than `varying`, explicit `out` variable rather than `gl_FragCoord`), and need an ES 3.0 context.

The workaround would be to flatten the `FILTRO()` macro to be a single line to avoid the line continuations (tested locally here on the Mali Offline Compiler and it compiles OK).